# How to make UIScrollView always scrollable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to make a class (ScrollableView : UIScrollView) that can always scroll vertically, similar to a TableView.  I've hardcoded a constant value to add to the content size so that it can always be scrollable.  For some strange reason though, it won't work when the value is 1; it will only work if the value is 4 or more.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height+1);
        self.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Is there another way to do this?  This doesn't seem to be the proper way.

Comment: Are you saying that the 1 in "frame.size.height+1" must be 4 or higher for it to work? That's most likely because the scroll view doesn't consider 3 pixels worthy of being scrolled into view, so I wouldn't bother too much about it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

How about setting

```
alwaysBounceVertical = YES
```

In Swift:

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Comment: This works in Swift as well! Simple and working solution